# Javascript: Recursion with for loop

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a problem with the current recursion. When I log this.memb and this.child, those two are the same values. However, it shouldn't be a case. this.child should be child of this.memb theoretically speaking.

```
buildGraphNode(treeNode){
    if(!(treeNode.data instanceof Array)){
      this.memb = this.member("" + treeNode.label, "" + treeNode.label, 'images/user1.png', '#d0000c', '', 'B');
      this.members.push(this.memb);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i<treeNode.children.length; i++) {
      this.child = this.buildGraphNode(treeNode.children[i]);

      if(this.child != null && this.memb !=null){
        console.log(this.memb);
        console.log(this.child);
        this.connections.push(this.link(this.memb,this.child));
      }
    }
    return this.memb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using excessive references to "this". You're operating on the same `this` object here, which will end up modifying the outer context. Try using local variables instead:

```
buildGraphNode(treeNode){
    if(!(treeNode.data instanceof Array)){
      var memb = this.member("" + treeNode.label, "" + treeNode.label, 'images/user1.png', '#d0000c', '', 'B');
      this.members.push(memb);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i<treeNode.children.length; i++) {
      var child = this.buildGraphNode(treeNode.children[i]);

      if(child != null && memb !=null){
        console.log(memb);
        console.log(child);
        this.connections.push(link(memb,child));
      }
    }
    return memb;
}
```

I have no idea how you're structuring the code, so there could be some needs to change other occurrences of `this`.

Comment: Without `var`, `const`, or `let` you are making global variables!

Comment: this. are all global variables. (It's Angular2 component)

Comment: If I make those variables inside the function. It will not pass the if(child != null) && memb !=null) as one variable will always be unset

Comment: Fixed the syntax. You need to pass the variable to the function if you want to have an initial value which will change in recursion.